# cannot publish interactive slidify slides in rPubs, error "AccessDenied" (link to rChart). What should I do?

Tags: publish, interactive, rcharts, slidify, rundeck

I made some solidify slides, would like to publish into rPubs.

They are rChart plots using morris.js library (mPlot). I can view the presentation all right using runDeck(). However, when I publish('index.html', host = 'rpubs'), the plots did not show up, other text are all right. Error is "AccessDenied", the link to the rChart is broken.

Please help

Comment: Can you show your codes ?

Comment: Would you join the discussion at https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/571. thanks